# How to assign value of property tag to hidden field in struts 2?

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to assign a value from a struts2 property tag to a hidden field but can't seem to get it to work. If I simply do

```
<s:property value="#session.user" />
```

the user name is shown on screen as expected. But I want to save this value to a hidden field on a form.

I've tried

```
<s:hidden id="user_name" name="user_name" value="%{session.user}" />
<s:hidden id="user_name" name="user_name" value="#session.user" />
<s:hidden id="user_name" name="user_name" value="%{#session.user}" />
```

But none of these work. I either get a blank value or a crash.

Comment: Try again. `%{#session.user}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since this was just to fill a hidden value in a form, I was able to just get a handle to the session on the back end the form was submitted to and pull the value out of the session.